# returning an array of vectors in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I'm having difficulty returning an array of string vectors. I have a function:

```
std::vector<std::string>* generatecVec(std::vector<std::string> strVec){
  std::vector<std::string> cVec[3];
  cVec[0].push_back("Test11");
  cVec[0].push_back("Test12");
  cVec[0].push_back("Test13");
  cVec[1].push_back("Test21");
  cVec[1].push_back("Test22");
  cVec[1].push_back("Test23");
  cVec[2].push_back("Test31");
  cVec[2].push_back("Test32");
  cVec[2].push_back("Test33");
  return cVec;
}
```

and later I use the function like

```
std::vector<std::string> *cVec = generatecVec(strVec);
for(std::vector<string>::iterator it = cVec[0].begin(); it != cVec[0].end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

but I keep getting segmentation fault. I realize I must be using pointers improperly, but how might I fix this? I use the array of vectors because it is very easy to refer to it by index (I only need three, non dynamic). Thanks!

Comment: I see you haven't accepted any answers to any of your questions. [Accept and/or upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168143/206447) an answer you found helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to something that only lives in the scope of the function. Once the function is done, `cVec` vanishes and the caller is left with a dangling pointer. I suggest returning an object that can actually be copied, such as an `std::array<std::vector<std::string> 3>`.

```
#include <array> // for std::array

std::array<std::vector<std::string>,3> generatecVec(/*std::vector<std::string> strVec*/){
  std::array<std::vector<std::string>,3> cVec;
  cVec[0].push_back("Test11");
  cVec[0].push_back("Test12");
  cVec[0].push_back("Test13");
  cVec[1].push_back("Test21");
  cVec[1].push_back("Test22");
  cVec[1].push_back("Test23");
  cVec[2].push_back("Test31");
  cVec[2].push_back("Test32");
  cVec[2].push_back("Test33");
  return cVec;
}
```

I have commented out `strvec` here because it seems to play no role in the function.

You can then use it like this (C++11 range based for loop syntax):

```
auto cVec = generatecVec(); // no strVec because it doesn't play any role
for(auto it = cVec[0].cbegin(); it != cVec[0].cend(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

Note that the `push_backs` may not be necessary if your compiler supports C++11 initializer list initialization.

If your compiler doesn't support `std::array`, try `std::tr1::array` from , or `boost::array`.

Answer (score 1):

As the others already explained, you are returning a local reference, that is garbage outside the function scope.
As a rule of thumb I try to avoid raw pointers as much as possible, since eventually I forget to delete a pointer after usage, or to initialize a pointer to start with.

When you return a std::array or std::vector you invoke the copy constructor and receive a fresh copy of the vector,array,etc... I personally tend to use boost shared_ptr for these situations, as they overcome most disadvantages that come with the classic C pointers

Comment: When you return an `std::array` or anything else by value you invoke a copy **semantically**, but the C++ standard allows a copy elision here, specifically return value optimization (RVO), and most current compilers implement that. So actually there is little point in returning a `shared_ptr`. If you did return a smart pointer, it should be a `unique_ptr` in this case.

Comment: this might be. but it is not guaranteed that every compiler uses such optimization. so it is better to write a clean code (might that shared_ptr or unique_ptr) than hoping that the target environment has such optimizations

Comment: I would say clean code is returning by value. It is more likely that the compiler will perform RVO than not, so I would turn the argument upside down: *if* you have a compiler that doesn't do RVO, *then* you can think of alternatives. One alternative would be to get a more modern compiler!

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a pointer to an automatic array, which is destroyed as it goes out of scope and your pointer points to a destroyed array full of destroyed vectors.

Use `std::array` and return it by value:

```
// This means: std::array of 3 std::vector<string>
//   Type--VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV  V-- Array size
std::array<std::vector<std::string>, 3> generatecVec(std::vector<std::string> strVec){
  return { {
     { "Test11", "Test12", "Test13" },
     { "Test21", "Test22", "Test23" },
     { "Test31", "Test32", "Test33" }
  } };
}

auto cVec = generatecVec(strVec);
for(auto it = cVec[0].begin(); it != cVec[0].end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that you use vector of string when you need collection of strings, but pointer when you need collection of vectors. Using typedef should help with abstraction of details and see possible solution:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> strings;
typedef std::vector<strings> strings_seq;

strings_seq generateVec()
{
  strings_seq cVec( 3 );
  cVec[0].push_back("Test11");
  cVec[0].push_back("Test12");
  cVec[0].push_back("Test13");
  cVec[1].push_back("Test21");
  cVec[1].push_back("Test22");
  cVec[1].push_back("Test23");
  cVec[2].push_back("Test31");
  cVec[2].push_back("Test32");
  cVec[2].push_back("Test33");
  return cVec;
}
```